# How to auto-preview a readme.md in a browser?

Tags: markdown, preview

I am writing a file called `README.md` for a Python project, and I would like to preview it while I write it. I used to do it, but I cannot remember the command line, and I cannot find it anywhere.

It was a Bash command-line linking my `.md` file to my browser, refreshing the page each time I saved changes in the `.md` file (written with any text editor).

Hence, I need to be able to write my file in my own text editor, and not online, and to see the result each time I save changes (without having to copy and paste what I have written to an online converter). It also worked with any text editor (I saw sublime-text plugins, but this is not what I am looking for), as it was linked to the `.md` file itself.

Answer (score 1):

[grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip) is one such tool.

`pip install grip` if you don't have it.

The preview is auto-reloading on changes, available by default under `http://localhost:6419/` in your browser, after running the `grip` command in the folder with the `README.md` file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the script your are talking about but I made a [PHP Parser for the Markdown syntax](https://github.com/atelierspierrot/markdown-extended) which embeds [an example script](https://github.com/atelierspierrot/markdown-extended/tree/master/demo/cgi-scripts) to ask Apache to parse any `.md` file in HTML output (see the `docs/` directory of the package for a simple documentation).

If you have a localhost with PHP running (PHP 5.3+), you can use it after a short vhost config. As the original file is parsed at each request, the page will be updated with your last modifications (but you will need to view it in your browser).